# Determine $Var(T)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given is the following:

Lets consider a random sample of size $n$ from a $U(-\theta, 2\theta)$ Distribution. We use $T = 2\bar{X}_n$ as an estimator for $\theta$.

Compute the variance of $T$.

What I did:

$Var(T) = Var(2\bar{X}_n) = 4Var(\bar{X}_n)$ which, using the fact that  its uniformly distributed comes out to be $3\theta^2$.

Yet for some reason, the answer is $\frac{3\theta^2}{n}$ which I don't quite understand. I do see that we have not just the variance of $X$ to be computed, but rather $\bar{X}_n$, but why would it add $\frac{1}{n}$ to the equation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i$ where $X_i$ are your samples. If you compute the variance. You should see why it comes out that way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Is this only the case in this particular distribution? @Gregory

Comment: No. It is true in general. If you expand the $\bar X_n$, you see it is the sum of (independent?) random samples from your distribution. The variance of course couldn't be the variance of a single draw (which is $3 \theta^2$).

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Gregory

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and $a$ and $b$ are constants then $\operatorname{Var}(aY+bZ)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(Y)+b^2\operatorname{Var}(Z)$. So:

- You have the $X_i$ iid each with variance $\sigma^2 = 3\theta^2$.
- So their sum $\sum X_i$ has variance $n\sigma^2 = n3\theta^2$.
- And their average $\bar X_n=\frac1n\sum X_i$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ times the sum, so has variance $\frac{1}{n^2}$ times the variance of the sum, i.e. $\frac{1}{n^2} n\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} 3\theta^2$.